# Can I answer with Python code?

Tags: discussion

If I have seen a question in AskUbuntu, would I be able to answer with a way to complete the question in Python. They haven't specified how they wanted it done, and I can't include a link because I can't find it.

EDIT:

Explaining the code as well!

Comment: Yes, if it answers the question :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure, why not? In principle, it is perfectly acceptable to give a solution in any language as long as it works on Ubuntu, but since Python is integral to Ubuntu and is a very popular language here, answers in Python are very welcome, and you will find many highly upvoted answers here which use it. Here are a couple of examples:

- [Script or function to return how many days from now until a given date](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858160/script-or-function-to-return-how-many-days-from-now-until-a-given-date/858182#858182)
- [How can I count files with a particular extension, and the directories they are in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023244/how-can-i-count-files-with-a-particular-extension-and-the-directories-they-are/1023281#1023281)

Comment: May I add the suggestion to answer not with **code only** - we usually encourage participants to explain what is happening :-))

Comment: @guntbert oh hahaha indeed. That's an interpretation of the question that didn't occur to me!